# Git pull with SSH under Windows behaves strangely

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am trying to pull from a GitLab repo with SSH on Windows. The keys should be correctly placed in the .ssh folder. At least they are recognised since it is not asked for a password. I tried OpenSSH and the ssh.exe included in Git.

When executing git pull, I first get the message

```
[...]  Permission denied
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After that, the GitLab cannot be reached from my entire local network, neither in the browser nor via SSH on different devices. Message is:

```
ssh: connect to host [...] port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Has anyone of you an idea what is happening?